# JavaFX Keep GridPane width inside Scene width and wrap text in Text

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, word-wrap

I have a JavaFX `BorderPane`, inside of which there is a `GridPane` for holding contents. The `GridPane` consists of two columns, one for a `Text` with a `Label` (both in a VBox) and one for a `Button`. The text column is supposed to be 80% width and the button column is supposed to be 20% width. **When I set the text of the `Text` and it is wider than the column, it wraps to the width of the VBox. However, when I change the size of the Window to make it wider and then shrink the Window back the text in the Text does not shrink back.**

**You can see my attempts at limiting the width in the `wireListeners` function of `TestMainView`.** I have tried different combos of things but have gotten nothing to work.

**Here is my code:**

*Launcher:*

```
package com.test.app;

import com.test.app.view.TestMainView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestGuiApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage initialStage) throws Exception {

        TestMainView mainView = new TestMainView();

        initialStage.setScene(new Scene(mainView.getView(), 300, 300));

        mainView.init();
        initialStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*GUI:*

```
package com.test.app.view;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class TestMainView {

    private BorderPane borderPane;
    private GridPane gridPane;
    private VBox viewBox;
    private VBox selectedItemsColumn;
    private Label selectedItemsTitleLabel;
    private Text selectedItemsList;
    private Button goButton;

    public TestMainView() {
        this.borderPane = new BorderPane();
    }

    public void init() {
        createView();
        wireListeners();
    }

    public BorderPane createView(){
        borderPane.setCenter(createCenterView());
        return borderPane;
    }

    public void wireListeners(){
        goButton.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            selectedItemsList.setText(selectedItemsList.getText() + "- X X X X X X");
        });

        //Tried the following listeners to prevent the text from growing otuside column size:

        //Keep border pane width matched to Scene
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(borderPane.getScene().heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.getScene().widthProperty());

        //Set text wrapping width to bind to its VBox, this worked
        selectedItemsList.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(selectedItemsColumn.widthProperty());

        //Set VBox width to match the gridpane column width
        selectedItemsColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(gridPane.getColumnConstraints().get(0).percentWidthProperty());

    }

    public VBox createCenterView(){
        viewBox = new VBox();
        viewBox.getChildren().add(createGridView());

        return viewBox;
    }

    public GridPane createGridView(){
        gridPane = new GridPane();

        selectedItemsColumn = new VBox();
        selectedItemsTitleLabel = new Label("Selected items:");
        selectedItemsList = new Text("X X X X X X");
        selectedItemsColumn.getChildren().addAll(selectedItemsTitleLabel, selectedItemsList);
        gridPane.add(selectedItemsColumn, 0, 0);

        goButton = new Button("Go!");
        gridPane.add(goButton, 1, 0);

        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col1.setPercentWidth(80);
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col2.setPercentWidth(20);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        return gridPane;
    }

    public Parent getView(){
        return borderPane;
    }

}
```

**How can I get the `Text` contents of my `VBox` to match their width to that of the `GridPane` column and not overflow the column?**

Comment: I would use a Label instead of Text. Didn't even know Text existed.

Comment: @rollback label does seem to get the job done. What is the behavioral difference between `Label` and `Text`? And what is the correct way to do this with `Text`?

Comment: Also @rollback if you want to answer the question with a fix to my example I will accept your answer. Otherwise, I will answer it myself